# How to open files with KMP as default?

Tags: file-format, kmplayer

I have downloaded some videos from Youtube. but their format is not KMP. It is "File". although when I right click on the file and click on "Open With" I can open it with KMP format. but the problem is, there isn't any option as "Open as default for this app". So I don't know how to convert these files to KMP.

Comment: How are you downloading the videos, and why do you think you'll get KMP files?

Comment: @harrymc I have been downloading videos a lot of times. It is the first time I have this issue. I use one of the site that you insert the link then the site generate downloading button.

Comment: Which site, and, again, why do you expect KMP files?

Comment: https://y2mate.guru/en8/

Comment: @harrymc It was not always KMP for example the file could be Windows Media Player which I could easily convert it it KMP (I mean it was something that can be played by double click). but now for first time the format is "File". I can play this format with KMP by using Open with. but I failed to change the format to KMP. (I want to send them to somebody else so I need the format be something like KMP or Windows Media Player etc)

Comment: I suggest using another site (unless you like porno). For example, [keepv](https://keepv.id/2/). Or a Windows app like [4K Video Downloader](https://www.4kdownload.com/products/product-videodownloader). In any case, using a website is not a subject for our site.